# Laravel - Policy multiple values - BelongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, policy

I have three tables: users, files and file_project.
Each file has an user_id.

The administrator can delete every file, but the user only the files he uploaded.

***view.blade.php***

[image]

***file table***

[image]

***file_project table***

[image]

After i submit the form i get these:

```
[
    "23",
    "22",
    "24"
]
```

So, now I can delete the files from Controller.
This is the Controller:

```
public function deleteSelected (Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->files;
    File::destroy($files);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

How can i use Policies and check for multiple ids?

I can now identify the records from file table, using the ids from $files

```
public function deleteSelected (Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->files;
    return $list = File::find($files);
}
```

And the response is:

[image]

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only users with permissions to delete the file you can use the following:

```
public function deleteSelected (Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->files;
    $loggedInUser = Auth::user();
    if(!$loggedInUser->isAdmin() || File::whereIn('id', $files)->where('user_id', $loggedInUser->id)->count() < count($files)) {
        abort(403);
    }
    File::destroy($files);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And then add the logic for isAdmin in your User Model